# My PHP email script isn't working?

Tags: php, post

So I made a script that sends emails, it uses a post method as it uses another programming language that posts the information and the php takes it and sends it. Now this was working until a few tries later where it hasn't sent? nothing has been received and I don't remember changing it.

Here is the script:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['username']) ||
        !isset($_POST['emailto']) ||
        !isset($_POST['emailsubject']) ||
        !isset($_POST['emailmessage'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $username = $_POST['username']; // required
    $emailto = $_POST['emailto']; // required
    $emailsubject = $_POST['emailsubject']; // required
    $emailmessage = $_POST['emailmessage']; //  required

    $error_message = "";
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$username)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($emailsubject) < 2) {
    died($error_message);
  }
  if(strlen($emailmessage) < 2) {
    died($error_message);
  }

    $email_message = "This information was sent by a computercraft user:\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }


    $email_message .= "Username: ".clean_string($username)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Subject: " .clean_string($emailsubject)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: \n".clean_string($emailmessage)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: ' . $username . "\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$username."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($emailto, $emailsubject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

{
    "True",
}

<?php
}
?>

Array
```

(
    [type] => 8
    [message] => Undefined variable: comments
    [file] => /customers/c/5/1/dannysmc.com/httpd.www/ccdb/email.php
    [line] => 31
)

//mail($emailto, $emailsubject, $email_message, $headers);
?>

{
    "True",
}

I add a true table at the bottom as the program that is receiving it takes that type of table.

If you can help that would be great, thanks

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: Are you on a public server?

Comment: PHP Mail will not work on localhost

Comment: Is `$username` just a name or an emailaddress as well?

Comment: `died()`.. From php.net: `bool died ([ string $status ] ) - Returns true when execution of the script has been terminated.` /jokess

Comment: I have added a reply underneath, that was the error I got... something to do with undefined variable?

Answer (score 1):

change your last part of code something like this to know more about the error

// create email headers

```
$headers = 'From: your-email-address'."\r\n".
'Reply-To: your-email-address'."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
if(mail($emailto, $emailsubject, $email_message, $headers)){
   echo 'TRUE';
}else{
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r(error_get_last()); //it will show you the error. Remove it on production 
}
?>
```

Comment: I got this?Array
(
    [type] => 8
    [message] => Undefined variable: comments
    [file] => /customers/c/5/1/dannysmc.com/httpd.www/ccdb/email.php
    [line] => 31
)

//mail($emailto, $emailsubject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

{
 "True",
}

Comment: remove `if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }` and try again

Comment: It just gives me this:  

//mail($emailto, $emailsubject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

{
 "True",
}